# How to find number of SP's hitting a specific table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a query that shows all stored procedures that are hitting to a specific table.

Comment: some kind of internet search perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....

```
  sp_depends 'dbo.TableName'
  GO
```